# CSS error while loading

Tags: css

When page is loading  div's that I tried to hide behind so it appears only when you go on it with an effect. I solved the problem with display:none;/display:block;, but then effect disappeared. How can I fix that without losing the effect ?

Picture; http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/4791/ssspl.png

Actual website; http://goo.gl/nTlZQ

Note: what I mean by error is text around butterflies.

Comment: have you tried using z-index?

Comment: which browser are you facing this problem?

Comment: z-index didnt solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this one to that;

```
display:block;overflow:hidden;
```